# Flask save data in webhook view

Tags: python, sql, flask, webhooks

I tried to search online to understand how data can be saved into database in webhook view. Unfortunately, I couldn't find any. My question is, is it possible to save data, eg session_id in webhook view ? and how ?

Answer (score 0):

When you speak of webhook view, I assume you are talking about a view - or route how it is called in Flask terminology.

Basically, I does not matter whether you want to save the data in a view or a helper method.

You have to make sure to extract the data from the request first.

But then, it basically looks like this:

```
from yourapp import User
me = User('admin', 'admin@example.com')
db.session.add(me)
db.session.commit()
```

This was taken from the flask-sqlalchemy documentation.

For a more complete tutorial, I'd recommend Miguel's tutorial:

https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world

You will learn all basic actions you can do with Flask, including saving data to a database.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.I know this stuffs. But the problem is that, I am trying to save to database if a transaction is successfully made using Stripe Webhook. But even when the code is correctly written, it does store in data base. The full code is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62733977/stripe-does-not-save-if-transaction-is-successful-in-flask