# stripe does not save if transaction is successful in flask

Tags: python, sql, flask, stripe-payments

I am trying to save some information in database if transaction is successful, in the stripe_webhook view. But not successful. is it that data cannot be saved directly in webhook ? so frustrating for me. I checked online for sample codes but could not find the ones that insert or update database for successful transaction.

```
from site.models import Post, Chapter, Order
import stripe
from sqlalchemy import desc

@posts.route("/paynow")
@login_required
def paynow():
    return render_template('paynow.html',)
        


@posts.route('/stripe_pay')
@login_required
def stripe_pay():
    amt = 10000
    stripe.api_key = current_app.config['STRIPE_SECRET_KEY']
    session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
        payment_method_types=['card'],
        line_items=[{
            'price_data': {
            'currency': 'usd',
            'product_data': {
            'name': 'T-shirt',
            },
            'unit_amount': amt,
            },
            'quantity': 1,
        }],
        mode='payment',
        success_url=url_for('posts.payment_success', _external=True) + '?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
        cancel_url=url_for('posts.paynow', _external=True),
    )
    return {
    'checkout_session_id': session['id'], 
    'checkout_public_key': current_app.config['STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY']
    }




@posts.route('/stripe_webhook', methods=['POST'])
@login_required
def stripe_webhook():
    print('WEBHOOK CALLED')

    if request.content_length > 1024 * 1024:
        print('REQUEST TOO BIG')
        abort(400)
    payload = request.get_data()
    sig_header = request.environ.get('HTTP_STRIPE_SIGNATURE')
    endpoint_secret = 'whsec_*************************************'
    event = None

    try:
        event = stripe.Webhook.construct_event(
            payload, sig_header, endpoint_secret
        )
    except ValueError as e:
        # Invalid payload
        print('INVALID PAYLOAD')
        return {}, 400
    except stripe.error.SignatureVerificationError as e:
        # Invalid signature
        print('INVALID SIGNATURE')
        return {}, 400

    # Handle the checkout.session.completed event
    if event['type'] == 'checkout.session.completed':
        session = event['data']['object']
        print(session)
        line_items = stripe.checkout.Session.list_line_items(session['id'], limit=1)
        print(line_items['data'][0]['description'])
        # save to database if successful
        save_order = Order(trans_id = "pppppppppp")
        db.session.add(save_order)
        db.session.commit()
        


    return {}

@posts.route('/payment_success')
@login_required
def payment_success():
    cart=Cart.query.filter_by(username = current_user.username).all()
    cart.status = "paid"
    db.session.commit()
    return render_template('payment_success.html')
```

Comment: What means `not successful.`? If you get error message when you run in console/terminal then show it in question. If you don't get error then use print to check if you run code which saves it. OR use logging to save in log information about executed code.

Comment: As I know other systems webhook should be without `login_required`. And you could use `print(event['type'])` to see what event's type you get. If you get event different then `checkout.session.completed` then it can't save it. See doc [Build a webhook endpoint](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/build) - it checks `payment_intent.succeeded`

Comment: What are you expecting to happen and what actually happens? If you receive the webhook and validate the signature, then you have a problem saving to your database only and it shouldn't matter whether this is during a webhook event handler or not.

Comment: @furas Thanks for your reply. Just that it doesn't print at all in the terminal. And this is making debugging harder for me. The is the codes that shows after successful payment:

Comment: @BrendanMoore The endpoint is correct, i mean the endpoint_secret. so the signature should be correct......although returns 400 in the terminal, which is still confusing me till now

Comment: you could add more `print()` - i.e display all variables - especially payload, use it before and after `if`, etc. You could use `print(e)` or even remove `try/except` to see more information about error.

Comment: still not printing. print statement does not work at all inside stripe_webhook view. Trying to figure out why but could'nt find out the reason. Its so frustrating.......always returning "?[31m?[1mPOST /stripe_webhook HTTP/1.1?[0m" 400 -     in the console....

Answer (score 1):

According to the Stripe customer care, I must used a live domain instead of local host

Comment: so you can not save data to database on test mode?